# Problem in My Merge Sort Implementation C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I've been learning about the merge sort algorithm, and I am having a bit of trouble. In my implementation, some of the numbers in the output are missing and others are repeated. I'm using vectors and following the algorithm described in Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et. al. and [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/).

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void merge_sort(vector<int>&, int, int);
void merge(vector<int>&, int, int, int);

int main() {
    
    vector<int> A = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3};
    int p = 0;
    int r = A.size() - 1;
    
    merge_sort(A, p, r);
    
    for(int num : A)
        cout << num << " ";
    
    return 0;
}

void merge_sort(vector<int>&A, int p, int r){
    if(p >= r)
        return;
    
    int mid = (p+r)/2;
    merge_sort(A, p, mid);
    merge_sort(A, mid+1, r);
    merge(A, p, mid, r);
}

void merge(vector<int>&A, int p, int mid, int r){
    int numLeft = mid - p + 1;
    int numRight = r - mid;
    
    //create two new vectors
    vector<int> left;
    vector<int> right;
    
    //copy elements over
    for(int i = 0; i < numLeft; i++)
        left.push_back(A[i]);
    for(int j = mid+1; j < (mid+1+numRight); j++)
        right.push_back(A[j]);
    
    //compare elements from the two arrays     
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    
    while(i < numLeft && j < numRight){
        if(left[i] <= right[j]){
            A[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            A[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    //check if one half terminated before the other
    while(i < numLeft){
        A[k] = left[i];
        k++; i++;
    }
    while(j < numRight){
        A[k] = right[j];
        k++; j++;
    }
}
```

Output: 1 2 3 6 1 3

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge` function assumes that you are sorting with `p=0`. You should copy from `p`, not from 0. Then put back with `k` starting from `p`:

```
    //copy elements over
    for (int i = p; i < p + numLeft; i++)
        left.push_back(A[i]);
    for (int j = mid + 1; j < (mid + 1 + numRight); j++)
        right.push_back(A[j]);

    //compare elements from the two arrays     
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = p;
```